# Caching issue when running Cucumber features with capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I've written a feature that tests whether some content appears on a page. The content is loaded dynamically via AJAX and the scenario is annotated with `@javascript`.

The weird part is: If I set `config.cache_classes = false` in `config/environments/test.rb`, everything just works fine and the step passes.

However, I would prefer the default of `config.cache_classes` being set to `true`. But with that setting, the step fails. I've been able to narrow down the cause of the failure to the AJAX call of the control whose content is being updated.

I've edited my Controller, even with drastic measures such as an `exit 1` to make absolutely sure that what happens is that an old, cached version of the Controller is being used.

1) Can I flush and regenerate the class cache manually? How would I tell Cucumber explicitly to use the current version of my class, without necessarily setting `config.cache_classes` to false?

2) Where does Rails cache the classes by default? I couldn't find anything useful answering this on the web.

My environment:

- Rails 3.2.8
- Cucumber 1.2.1
- cucumber-rails 1.3.0
- capybara 1.1.2
- capybara-webkit 0.12.1 (`javascript_driver` is `:webkit`, but error persists with `:selenium`)

Comment: Super old question, and I can't reproduce this issue myself without more detail, but for the Googlers I'll mention that you can manually clear the Rails cache by running `rake tmp:cache:clear` from the terminal. That might solve this issue